# BooleanComputation and superfunctions / meta-algorithms

Tags: equation-solving, boolean-computation

Background : 
A friend intends to model biological systems using boolean equations. He needed to write a solver to find out all possible solutions for such equations. 
I suggested WL as a viable candidate for the same compared to other options. I believe WL12.1 would a catalyst because of the rich functionalities it supports out of the box.
Since he is a biologist, I am helping out with outlining the solution and programming it.
I have explored the reference docs and have gotten confused.

Main Questions :
Why does BooleanComputation not have a Solve[...] function ? 
How does BooleanComputation relate with EquationSOlving, PolynomialEquations ?
Are there any superfunctions or meta-algorithms at work ?
Do I need to write a BSolve[...] ?

I would appreciate guidance for these. Many thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you give an example of Boolean equations your friend is studying?

Comment: It's called `SatisfiabilityInstances`. You may want to read up on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem